# How to create keyboard short cut for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating Chrome Extension. Keyboard short cut "Command+Shift+O" had worked in manifest version 2

How ever manifest version 3 dose not work "Command+Shift+O".

```
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+O",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+O",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+O",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+O"
      }
    }
  }
```

When I change "O" to "Y", It works fine.

```
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  }
```

I think my keyboard short cut does not conflict with other Keys.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Or should I change The short cut keys?

Comment: It's a bug fixed in Chrome 103, https://crbug.com/1190476.

Comment: Thank you! My chrome version is `Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64)`. I confirmed keyboard short cut works fine in `Version 103.0.5060.33 (Official Build) beta (x86_64)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @wOxxOm. This issue fixed on Chrome Version 103.0.5060.33.